# How to load bootstrap-waitingfor.js(a Progressbar) on every postback on page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap-waitingfor.js,its a bootstrap modal progressbar, On every OnClientClick event i have to load

```html
waitingDialog.show('Please Wait', {dialogSize: 'sm', progressType: 'warning'});" Text="Import" />
```

If i have 100 buttons so i have to implement it hundred times. I want this to load on every post back caused by any Control on any page in my project. Is it possible?
I'm using asp.net web form and using master page

Comment: Why are you avoiding  UpdatePanel ?

Comment: Please be more specific , i'm using update panel on some page but not in every page